# Elasticsearch search from array content

Tags: elasticsearch

Let say I have following 3 documents in ES index.

```
{
    someId: 'A'
}

{
    someId: 'B'
}

{
    someId: 'C'
}
```

Let's say I have an array of *someId* `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`. What I need to find is which of elements in the array is in ES.

For the above example ES contains document for someId ['A', 'B', 'C'] but not for ['D', 'E']

Is there an ES query to achieve it?

Comment: Do you want to search which documents contains 'A' and 'B' and 'C', which documents contains 'A' or 'B' or 'C', or do you want to convert someId values to an array ['A', 'B', 'C'] for each documents (this is not a 'search' in this case) ?

Comment: Yes, main goal is not finding document. Instead filtering the array.

Comment: If you are trying to merge the fields or the array, no. Elasticsearch works with tokens and inverted indexes. In order to be able to search for individual words within a big block of text, Lucene tokenizes the text into individual terms, and adds each term to the inverted index separately. Even [Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) are designed to convert text into tokens.

Comment: Then I need to do that functionality in my code. Then how to find the documents containing "A" or "B" or "C".